# Как правильно обработать POST запрос Spring Boot через JpaRepository

Tags: java, json, spring, formdata

Трудность вот в чём; в POST запросе на сервер передаётся не только json добавляемого в базу объекта, но ещё и файл (картинка). Я добавляю в тело запроса объект FormData, у него два параметра, один с json другой с файлом.

При обработке таког запроса в контроллере, через аннотацию параметра @RequestParam, с получением файла проблем нет, а вот с получением объекта из json есть. Раньше когда в запросе был только json использовался @RequestBody и Spring сам парсил джейсоновскую строку в нужный объект, из @RequestParam он этого делать не хочет (или я что-то не то делаю).

Понятно что можно распарсить и создать объект самому вручную. Но опять же вопрос, как правильно это делать? Можно обойтись только библиотекой Spring или нужно ставить ещё скажем Gson?

Comment: Вместо `RequestParam` используйте [RequestPart](https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests#using-requestpart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createSubject")
public void createSubject(@RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) Collection<MultipartFile> files, @RequestPart("subject") String subjectInString) {
        subjectService.createSubject(subjectInString, files);
}
```

Вместо Collection можно использовать просто MultipartFile

**Service**

```
@Transactional
@Override
    public void createSubject(String subjectInString, Collection<MultipartFile> files) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Subject subject = objectMapper.readValue(subjectInString, Subject.class);
            if (subject != null) {
                if (!subjectRepository.existsByNameAndType(subject.getName(), subject.getType())) {
                    if (files != null && !files.isEmpty())
                        addFilesToSubject(files, subject);

                    subjectRepository.save(subject);
                } else {
                    throw new SubjectAlreadyExistsException(subject.getName(), subject.getType().name());
                }
            } else {
                throw new SubjectIsNullException();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new SubjectIsNullException();
        }

}
```

**Пример клиента Angular**

**Service**

```
 public createSubject(subject: Subject, files: File[]): Observable<any>{
        let data = new FormData();
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
        this.appendFiles(files, data);
        data.append('subject', JSON.stringify(subject));
        return this.http.post(API_URL + 'subject/createSubject', data, {headers: headers});
    }

 private appendFiles(files: File[], data:FormData){
        for (let file of files) {            
            data.append('file', file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Kzz xD, благодаря Вашей подсказке понял, забыл указать jackson-databind в зависимостях. Спасибо.

Comment: @АндрейСеменютенко :) Хорошего дня !